# Multiple Blogs In Single Jekyll Website

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Is there a way I can have a single Jekyll website have more than one blog? I currently want to have two blogs in one site.

Comment: It seems like Google can help here: have you tried any solutions?
Take a look here: http://www.garron.me/blog/multi-blog-site-jekyll.html

Comment: I have already looked at it. It does help but I wanted a way to implement many more blogging features like archives,displaying latest post etc. Thanks neways

Answer (score 30):

I am the author of the page http://www.garron.me/blog/multi-blog-site-jekyll.html

Considering that you need individual archives pages, and latest post per individual blog. Just use something like this:

Create a file archives-blog-1.html and fill it with:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.categories contains 'blog1' %}
    <div class="post">
        <h3 class="title"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
        <p class="meta">Date: {{ post.date }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That will give you a list of all post in blog1, you can do the same for blog2. That page can be anyplace you want.

For the latest post, you can use the same code but enclosed between:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}
....
{% endfor %}
```

That will give you the lastes 5 posts... I am using this

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}

  <div class="post">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title | truncate:200 }} </a><small>{{ post.date }}</small>
         {% if post.summary %}
            <p class="entry">{{ post.summary }}</p>
         {% endif %}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In my index page. http://www.garron.me/index.html ... under the sub-title (From the blogs)
I am not limiting to any category, so posts from all blogs appear there, you can limit with `{% if post.categories contains 'blog1' %}`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 16):

There's a simpler solution than any of the answers so far.

Folder structure:

`- blog1/
  - _posts/
- blog2/
  - _posts/`

Then in the index.html for blog1, use `site.categories.blog1` instead of `site.posts`.

See the documentation for "site.categories" and "page.categories" in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/

Answer (score 1):

I used two separate Jekyll installations to run [two blogs on the same domain](http://hypertext.net/2013/01/jekyll); if your blogs are going to live in separate root dirs (mine are at `/` and `/photos/`), then I'd recommend this approach. I also [described how I merged both blogs' sitemap.xml files](http://hypertext.net/2013/01/merge-sitemaps).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look into the [data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) feature. You can put `.markdown` files in a separate folder in your `source` and link to them as you post. This does mean that in order to make a post, you'll need to write a data file entry, but you can host as many "blogs" as you'd like, each with their own folder. Posts will automatically have the folder they're in as the url. I use this method for my own personal blog and portfolio.

Either that, or you may want to look into collections: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ggarron's answer, there's a short version of filtering by categories:

```
{% assign filtered_posts = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.categories contains 'blog1'" %}
```

The advantage of assigning to a variable is that one can replace all uses of `site.posts` with `filtered_posts` and keep consistency. For example, I have a snippet to get the first post of the list:

```
{% assign first_post = filtered_posts | first %}
```

This works as expected.