# Is there any way to roll two paginated blogs into one Jekyll site, hosted in a single GitHub Pages repo?

Tags: ruby, configuration, pagination, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site that uses the jekyll-paginate plugin and is hosted by GitHub Pages, pretty standard.

Does anybody know of other solutions to handle pagination such that I could build two blogs from the same site at domain/blog1 and domain/blog2 [using this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196173/2005759), but also retain pagination?

Retaining the current pagination *design* is not a priority. Creative ideas that require redesign are welcome.

I know [jekyll-paginate-multiple](https://github.com/scandio/jekyll-paginate-multiple) exists, but GitHub Pages does not support it natively, and I would have to maintain two repos to maintain the site code and build artifacts separately, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use any custom Plugin/Gem with your GitHub Pages hosted Jekyll blog

Here is how you **CAN** use any custom plugin on a GitHub Pages hosted website. I use this on my own blog so I'm 100% certain that it works. The basic idea is that you use TravisCI to build your custom Jekyll site on a `staging` branch and then push it automatically to your GitHubPages `master` branch that serves your website. Here comes the quick walkthrough:

a) you configure GitHub Pages to host from the `docs` folder of your `master` branch

b) you add and configure a `staging` branch to be the default branch of your repo, there is where you do all your local work, releases work through setting a git tag on this branch

c) you use `_config.yml` file to set your `destination` directory to `docs`

```
# _config.yml
destination: docs
```

d) to avoid build issues with Travis CI you can add `Gemfile.lock` to your `.gitignore` file and the `docs` folder to your local `.git/info/exclude` since you don't want to push them anymore. To exclude the `docs` folder from a local push is optional, but for me that works best. You also may need to delete the `Gemfile.lock` first and then let Travis CI pick the fitting versions for the selected Docker OS, otherwise you can run into version conflicts which can be pretty hard to fix.

e) to deploy with Travis CI into `production` a.k.a. your live site you add a `.travis.yml` file alike :

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.6.3
install:
  - bundle install
script:
  - JEKYLL_ENV="production" bundle exec jekyll build
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash script/deploy.sh
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    branch: staging

branches:
  only:
    - staging
    - /\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?(-\S*)?$/
env:
  global:
  - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true
  - secure: TRAVIS_SECRET_KEY_FOR_GITHUB_CREDENTIALS
sudo: false
cache: bundler
notifications:
  email: false
```

g) `script/deploy.sh` looks somewhat like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bundle install
JEKYLL_ENV="production" bundle exec jekyll build
git status
git add .
git commit -m"[skip travis] Automated build"
git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:$PSW@github.com/YOUR_GIT_USER/YOUR_REPO.git
git push origin HEAD:master --force
```

e) to get your encrypted `TRAVIS_SECRET_KEY_FOR_GITHUB_CREDENTIALS` in `.travis.yml` with the used `$PSW` variable used in the deploy script, just follow the [Encryption Key Doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#usage)

Once this configuration is done, you can use any Gem the same way as on localhost since the building part is not done by GitHub anymore but TravisCI.

#### Conclusion

You just work on `staging` and only let Travis CI push to your master branch. You use tags in the form `1.0.0` to deploy. All you need to do now is to add `jekyll-paginate-multiple` to your `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` and you are ready.

If anyone is interested in more details for those step, have a look at this [Blog Post](https://rasta.online/education/software-development/2020/07/28/configure-repo-and-travis-ci-to-build-any-custom-jekyll-plugin-for-github-pages.html) detailing the issue

Comment: For my simple blog with not very many posts and low posting frequency, I designed my way around this. I got rid of pagination and am putting in a list of post titles after excerpts for the newest 3-5. But for when I end up growing beyond that, I like this solution!

Answer (score 0):

If `jekyll-paginate-multiple` works in your context, you can use it on GitHub pages as well.

All you need to do is to copy

```
https://github.com/scandio/jekyll-paginate-multiple/blob/master/lib/jekyll-paginate-multiple.rb
```

into your repos `_plugins` folder and you are good to go.

Comment: Are you sure that works? GH Pages [documentation says](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#plugins) I can't use third party plugins, but at the same time never mentions anything about the _plugins directory one way or another. Quick EDIT: Yeah, they build with the `--safe` flag, which disables custom plugins.

Comment: Allowed plugins on Github Pages : https://pages.github.com/versions/

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry since I didn't test it at first. I posted a second answer though that outlines how you can add any custom Gem/Plugin together with GitHub Pages hosted Jekyll blogs, including `jekyll-paginate-multiple`